# Eclipse web app architype

Tags: java, eclipse

I am studying Servlet/JSP and working with Eclipse. I have a mind create a simple web app. My question is how I should create it.

There are three ways:

1. maven-project archetype-web app
2. enterprise app project
3. dynamic web-project.

What is the difference? From other sources, I get a different information.

Comment: This tutorial may help you: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html

Comment: I suggest starting with #3 first. It is the simplest approach to get something up and running, using an Eclipse wizard (File->New->Project->Web->Dynamic Web Project). Then move to #1, using Maven to build your project and manage dependencies. Finally move to #2 which involves the use of Java EE (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html).